# How to draw 2D matrix of squares on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, sprite-kit, 2d

What is the best way how to draw a matrix of squares on iOS using SpriteKit? I am complete iOS beginner and I'm not sure what is the correct approach.

I was thinking creating a sprite representing a picture of a square and than add that sprite several times to specific locations. The data in the matrix will change over time and I need to reflect that in what is being drawn on the screen, though the shape of the matrix will remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get a basic 2d matrix of squares on the scree. If you need to keep track of these tile sprites, you can create an array of tiles and modify them elsewhere in your code. Hope this is helpful.

```
func setupMap() {
    let tilesWide = 10
    let tilesTall = 10

    for i in 0..<tilesWide {
        for j in 0..<tilesTall {
            let tile = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
            tile.anchorPoint = CGPointZero

            let x = CGFloat(i) * tile.size.width
            let y = CGFloat(j) * tile.size.height

            tile.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            self.addChild(tile)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update for Swift3 :

```
func setupMap() {
    let tilesWide = 10
    let tilesTall = 10

    for i in 0..<tilesWide {
        for j in 0..<tilesTall {
            let tile = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
            tile.anchorPoint = .zero

            let x = CGFloat(i) * tile.size.width
            let y = CGFloat(j) * tile.size.height

            tile.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            self.addChild(tile)
        }
    }
}
```